# Opensource nodejs devices management

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for a nodejs webbased opensource application to manage hundred of devices. Devices are divided into several models. Each model defines both mandatory and optional parameters that each device has (ip, location to name a few). In addition, information such as documents and images are associated to each device. Finally, devices can be logically connected one to each other.

Is there any project in github for such requirements?

Comment: This is off topic for SO - Highly likely to be very opinion based.

Comment: Question updated to ask for a list of projects

Comment: Why don't you google it or write your own logic for your specific requirement.

Comment: re-inventing the wheel is completely useless in such situations. For the requirements I have https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev fits well

Answer (score 0):

The best open source project found for such requirements is https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev